# Facebook Like Button doesn't share

Tags: facebook, button, share

I have add like button on my webpage www.zabavax.com (iframe). Count is work ok, but like button doesn't share post (link) on Facebook.

P.S. Like button on the left side and after post. When i click on right or after post like button liked link dont show on my Timeline and on friends news feed

Comment: Please update your question with more information about the problem.  Which like button are you referring to?

Comment: Like button on the left side and after post.

Comment: the like button on the left side does work.  The likes on the posts don't show up on the news feed but they do appear in the [activity log](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity)...

Comment: yes, but whay dont show in news feed? Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think Facebook has changed the behaviour of the like button. A link will be shared ONLY if the user adds a comment.

Comment: I think you are correct on this, but I'm experiencing an issue where after adding the comment in the dialog and clicking "post" the comment never posts and the dialog box is stuck. Have you ever seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Your like button in the top right corner of your URL functions correctly.
I was able to post to my profile when I clicked on it.

I believe your issue is with the first-time popup that appears (also with its own like button)  When I clicked that like button the popup disappeared and I didn't manage to post to my profile.

Comment: Like button on left side and after post dont work. Before 5 days all work ok with popup, but now both like dont share on users news feeds.